# How to configure alias path jump for scss in vscode?

Tags: node.js, sass, visual-studio-code, vite

In [my project](https://github.com/bato3/sveltekit-attractions-ui-test) (`vite` powered) I use aliases. I have configured it, and they work for build and jump in `.ts`.

I have problem when I try to jump in `src/app.scss` files.

```
// case 1: vite OK, vscode: Fail
@import '$bs/bootstrap';

// case 2: vite Fail, vscode OK
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

###### case 1

When I try to go through an alias to a file with Ctrl + Click, vscode doesn't find the file and asks if I want to create it.
[image: vscode resolve problem]

###### case 2

For vscode there is an alias `~` on `node_modules`, but then you cannot compile the project in vite.
[image: vite resolve problem]

#### I tried

###### [Vite + tsconfig.json](https://codingcat.dev/post/make-pathing-easier-with-aliases-in-sveltekit)

```js
vite: {
            resolve: {
                alias: {
                    '$bs': path.resolve('./node_modules/bootstrap/scss'),
                }
            }
```

And in `tsconfig.joson` (and I create `jsonfig.json`):

```json
        "paths": {
            "$lib": ["src/lib"],
            "$lib/*": ["src/lib/*"],
            "$bs/*": ["node_modules/bootstrap/scss/*"],
        }
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.js", "src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.svelte"]
```

##### Couple vscode extensions:

- "wudy.vs-alias-jump",
- "paulgui.alias-jump",
- "svelte.svelte-vscode",
- "mariocadenas.alias-resolver"

```json
"vs-alias-jump.alias": {
    "$lib": "${folder}/src/lib",
    "$bs": "${folder}/node_modules/bootstrap/scss",
},
"aliasJump.alias": {
    "$bs": "/node_modules/bootstrap/scss",
},
"jumpToAliasFile.alias": {
    "$bs": "D:/dev/node/layout-test/sveltekit-attractions-ui-test/node_modules/bootstrap/scss",
}
```

### ~~//edit 1~~

~~I found a working solution, but I'm not entirely happy with it.~~

**Is it possible to somehow change the vscode resolver?**

```json
resolve.alias: {
        '~bootstrap': path.resolve( './node_modules/bootstrap')
}
```

### edit 2

I don't know what happen, but on other PC this don't works. (I saw some vite message about discovering new dependency and this starts work...)